# Factory_girl: one attribute's definition is dependent upon another one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

How can you build a factory where one attribute is dependent upon the other?

```
  factory :event do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "Event #{n}" }
    sequence(:description) { |n| "More detailed info about event #{n}" }
    start_at { rand(1..100).days.from_now }
    end_at { start_at + rand(1..5).hours }   # <=== referencing start_at
  end
```

Using this gives a `NameError: uninitialized constant Event` my specs and I assume it's from trying to set `end_at` to a value dependent upon value of `start_at`. How to do this? Trying to instantiate a few dozen valid "events".  Thanks.

Comment: The syntax you are using seems to be the right one to define [dependent attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#dependent-attributes). From the error I see, it looks more like it can't find the Event model. Did you define it?

Comment: Yup. you're right. See comment below...

Answer (score 1):

this is described here https://thoughtbot.github.io/factory_bot/dependent-attributes/summary.html

your syntax was correct but your error was because the gem couldn't find the Event model. unrelated to dependent attributes, as you subsequently discovered.

Answer (score 0):

The error does not occur because of something wrong inside your factory block.
The Event class is not defined correctly.

Could you please show your Event model?

Perhaps its nested in a module? Then you could do this:

```
factory :event, :class => 'ModuleName::Event' do
  ...
end
```

Comment: I actually had named this factory `:eventize` to distinguish it from the *static* factory. Wanted one with variable attributes and one w/out. I suppose that's unnecessary but that's what was creating the error. Didn't fully understand inner-workings of Factory_girl. So, in mean time I've just added `parent: event` and replaced all attributes. seems to work...but i'm probably going about Factories in general the wrong way!?!

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want to do is something like this:

```
factory :event do
  title 'foo'
  description "bar"
  other_attributes "baz"

  factory :dynamic_event do
    sequence(:title) { |n| "Event #{n}" }
  end

end
```

The `:dynamic_event` factory will inherit all attributes from the event factory, but overrides that ones given inside its block. (The `title`in a sequence in this example)

Comment: Does `:dynamic_` have special meaning in Factory_girl? Because, if not, then I don't think this will work as it's basically what I originally had `factory :eventize do`.

Comment: no `dynamic_` was just a name in my head ;-)
Perhaps I did not get what you want to do...

Comment: Well, as I've *just* discovered, you can't have a factory with a name that doesn't correspond to a model, unless you declare it's `:parent` to be another factory of a valid model.

Comment: You can. In my example above you must have a model named Event, but the nested factory inside that block does not need a model named dynamic_event.

You also can declare the class for the factory, like in my first example. Then you can name it like you want.